# Multithreading summation

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I'm tying to sum a big length array (e.g. 30,000,000) and optimizing the time consumption.

I'm following up the multithreading idea ... i wrote a code for 3000 length array for instance and get divided by 3 different threads and get the sum of each third and use just sequential addition in the last step ..

Unfortunately i have a an error in handling exceptions in the 3 threads. 
as it is mentioned down in the console message .

Any help ?

```
//File Name : ThreadClassDemo.java

package experiment;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class ThreadClassDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double xarr[] = new double[3000]; 
    Arrays.fill(xarr, 1);
    System.out.println(xarr[2999]);

    double x=0;
    Runnable first1 = new DisplayMessage(x,xarr,0,999);
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(first1);
    thread1.setDaemon(true);
    thread1.start();


    double y=0;
    Runnable first2 = new DisplayMessage(y,xarr,1000,1999);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(first2);
    thread2.setDaemon(true);
    thread2.start();

    double z=0;
    Runnable first3 = new DisplayMessage(z,xarr,2000,2999);
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(first3);
    thread3.setDaemon(true);
    thread3.start();



    }
}
```

---

```
  package experiment;
 //File Name : DisplayMessage.java
//Create a thread to implement Runnable
public class DisplayMessage implements Runnable {
public double result = 0;
private double arr[];
private int num1;
private int num2;

public DisplayMessage(double i, double[] xarr, int j, int k) {
    result = i;
    xarr = arr;
    num1 = j;
    num2 = k;
}

/*
 * public DisplayMessage(String message) { this.message = message; }
 */
public double getresult(){return result;}
public void run() {

    try {           
        System.out.println("dsfsfs");
        for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i++) {
            result += arr[i];
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {          
        System.out.println(" interrupted.");
    }

   }
 }
```

**Console :**

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" Exception in thread "Thread-2" Exception in thread "Thread-1"
```

Comment: If you're on Java 8, you can do this _much_ more easily with streams...

Comment: You have your assignment backwards in your constructor. It should be `arr = xarr;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Java 8 you can do

```
long sum = IntStream.of(array).parallel().sum();
```

This will break up the array so that every CPU on you machine can be used.

Note: if you have only a few thousand numbers to add up you might find that starting a thread takes longer. i.e. You need to be summing a really big array to see an improvement.